# making a "dropdown" function in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Often times I get data in the format of an excel spreadsheet that looks like:

```
Name1 Data
      Data
      Data  
Name2 Data
      Data
      Data
....
```

When I read this into R, the blank rows come us as NA and then I always write some ad hoc code to fill it in so that it looks like:

```
Name1 Data
Name1 Data
Name1 Data
Name2 Data
Name2 Data
Name2 Data
....
```

Typically, I just do this with a for loop that keeps track of the last name and every time I see an NA I fill it in. The next time I see something in the name column, I then save the new name and start writing that.

I was wondering if there was a prettier, R vectorized version of that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `na.locf` in the `zoo` package.eg  `na.locf(df$Col1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
  indx <- !is.na(df$Col1)
  df$Col1 <- df$Col1[indx][cumsum(indx)] 
  df
  #   Col1 Col2
  #1 Name1 Data
  #2 Name1 Data
  #3 Name1 Data
  #4 Name2 Data
  #5 Name2 Data
  #6 Name2 Data
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Name1", NA, NA, "Name2", NA, NA),
 Col2 = c("Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data")), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

I really like @akrun's answer, very clever! I may try to switch to that method in the future. Another option is `zoo::na.locf`, (*locf* stands for *last observation carried forward*). Using akrun's data

```
> df$Col1 <- zoo::na.locf(df$Col1)
> df
   Col1 Col2
1 Name1 Data
2 Name1 Data
3 Name1 Data
4 Name2 Data
5 Name2 Data
6 Name2 Data
```

`na.locf` has a features that help it work in varied cases... options for what to do with leading `NA`s, you can carry backward rather than forward, and a few other special handlers (see `?na.locf`).

(data)

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Name1", NA, NA, "Name2", NA, NA),
 Col2 = c("Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data")), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using the `Reduce` function:

```
> df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("Name1", NA, NA, "Name2", NA, NA),
+        Col2 = c("Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data", "Data")), .Names = c("Col1", 
+        "Col2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
> 
> df
   Col1 Col2
1 Name1 Data
2  <NA> Data
3  <NA> Data
4 Name2 Data
5  <NA> Data
6  <NA> Data
> df$Col1 <- Reduce(function(a,b) if(is.na(b)) a else b, df$Col1,
+ accumulate=TRUE)
> df
   Col1 Col2
1 Name1 Data
2 Name1 Data
3 Name1 Data
4 Name2 Data
5 Name2 Data
6 Name2 Data
>
```